# Get the excerpt of post_content

Tags: excerpt, post-content, custom-content

Hi guys can you explain me how to get a excerpt length of 15 for the post_content in my code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2', 'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-aside',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ), 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-image',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
) );


$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo 
    '<div class="news_home">
  <div class="content_left"><img src="'.get_permalink($recent['ID'])."'>".get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']).'</div>
  <div class="content_right">
    <h4> '.   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</h4>
    <span>'. mysql2date('j.m.Y', $recent["post_date"]) .'</span>
    <div class="HR_ornament">
      <hr class="news_hr"/>
      <div class="ornament_news"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="news_text">'.( __($recent["post_content"])).'
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">[...]</a> 
    </p></div>
</div> 
';
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you did some more research you would find this as it's been asked many times before.

If you just want all expert to return the value of 15 then you have to add something like this to your `functions.php`

```
// Customize excerpt word count length
function custom_excerpt_length() {
    return 15;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

This will make all excerpt return 15 characters.

**Updated:**

I don't see `the_excerpt` in your code so you will have to add this aswell

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Comment: You are right i found this solution... But it's not working for me because I don't use the expression <?php the_excerpt(); ?> for calling the excerpt.

I get the content of the post by using:     
echo '
<p class="news_text">'.( __($recent["post_content"])).''; 

and i want to add a custom length of 15 characters for this content.

Comment: May I ask why you're not using the expression `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` cause surely that is the easiest way to do it, if you want a class for it you can just wrap `<p>` tags around the `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` also I'm fairly new to WordPress so other than the answer I gave you above I can't help xD Good luck anyways :)